# Trigger a function on selection of text from textbox

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I am using angular 8.

I have a textbox, which consists of some text. I want the user to select the text, Once the selection is over, I want to call a function with the selected text as a parameter.

Here is the selected textbox.

[image]

Now, when the reaction is selected, I want to call a function. Is there any way, I can do this in Angular 8.

Comment: You can give a look at `getSelection` which is a webapi but doesn't work everywhere (for inputs and textarea you should use `setSelectionRange`) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `textbox` is a `HTML textarea`, you define the `select` event handler as follows in your template (here it points to the `onTextSelected` method from your component class).

```
<textarea #textbox (select)="onTextSelected()">{{ text }}</textarea>
```

In your component class, you should get a reference to the `textare` by the use of the [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator. Then you need to implement the `onTextSelected` method.

```
@ViewChild('textbox', { static: false}) textAreaRef: ElementRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>;

onTextSelected(): void {
  const textArea = this.textAreaRef.nativeElement;
  this.selectedText = textArea.value.substring(textArea.selectionStart, textArea.selectionEnd);
}
```

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vaxjid?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

> In case you really want to call the method with the selected text, you can change your template as follows and get rid of `@ViewChild` at the same time.
>
> `<textarea #textbox (select)="onTextSelected(textbox.value.substring(textbox.selectionStart, textbox.selectionEnd))">{{ text }}</textarea>`
>
> This is is shown in the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ioz2dh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thank You So Much @uminder , It is working exactly how I wanted.

Comment: Glad I could help you.